# Index out of range when i use to celll( Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview, uiimage

people, I have this issue when I try back image from different cell
(Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range)

what I'm doing here ?
I'm trying to build an Instagram clone and in my home view controller that what should posts show up. I make navigation with a table view and that table view has 2 cell with the different identifier. cell number 1 it's a header that brings data from users table to my username label and profile image. and cell number 2 its for posts its should bring post data like image and caption. I use firebase database.

my code :

```
import UIKit

import FirebaseAuth

import FirebaseDatabase

class HomeViewController: UIViewController ,UITableViewDelegate  {


    @IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!
    var posts = [Post]()
    var users = [UserD]()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableview.dataSource = self
        loadposts()
        userDetal()

     //   var post = Post(captiontxt: "test", photoUrlString: "urll")
     //   print(post.caption)
     //   print(post.photoUrl)

    }

    func loadposts() {
        Database.database().reference().child("posts").observe(.childAdded){ (snapshot: DataSnapshot)in
            print(Thread.isMainThread)
              if let dict = snapshot.value  as? [String: Any]{
                let captiontxt = dict["caption"] as! String
                let photoUrlString = dict["photoUrl"] as! String
               let post = Post(captiontxt: captiontxt, photoUrlString: photoUrlString)
                self.posts.append(post)
                print(self.posts)
                self.tableview.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
    func userDetal() {
        Database.database().reference().child("users").observe(.childAdded){ (snapshot: DataSnapshot)in
            print(Thread.isMainThread)
            if let dict = snapshot.value  as? [String: Any]{
                let usernametxt = dict["username"] as! String
                let profileImageUrlString = dict["profileImageUrl"] as! String
                let user = UserD(usernametxt: usernametxt, profileImageUrlString: profileImageUrlString)
                self.users.append(user)
                print(self.users)
                self.tableview.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }

    @IBAction func logout(_ sender: Any) {
        do {
            try Auth.auth().signOut()
        }catch let logoutErrorr{
            print(logoutErrorr)
        }
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Start", bundle: nil)
        let signinVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SigninViewController")
        self.present(signinVC, animated: true, completion: nil)


    }

}

extension HomeViewController: UITableViewDataSource{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return posts.count

    }
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return users.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if indexPath.row == 0{
         let cell = tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "imagecell", for: indexPath) as! PostCellTableViewCell

        cell.postimage.image = nil

        cell.tag += 1
        let tag = cell.tag

        cell.captionLabel.text = posts[indexPath.row].caption

        let photoUrl = posts[indexPath.row].photoUrl

        getImage(url: photoUrl) { photo in
            if photo != nil {
                if cell.tag == tag {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        cell.postimage.image = photo

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return cell
        } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
            let cell = tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "postcell", for: indexPath) as! HeaderTableViewCell

            cell.userimage.image = nil

            cell.tag += 1
            let tag = cell.tag
            cell.usernamelabel.text = users[indexPath.row].username 
            //Error showing here????????????????????????????????????
            let profileImageUrl = users[indexPath.row].profileImageUrl

            getImage(url: profileImageUrl) { photo in
                if photo != nil {
                    if cell.tag == tag {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            cell.userimage.image = photo


                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return cell
        }
        return UITableViewCell()

    }


    func getImage(url: String, completion: @escaping (UIImage?) -> ()) {
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: url)!) { data, response, error in
            if error == nil {
                completion(UIImage(data: data!))
            } else {
                completion(nil)
            }
            }.resume()
}
}
```

Comment: You are at a wrong place.  This web site doesn't run an error-tracking service.  If you need assistance, explain what you are trying to do.  Nobody even knows what kind of data you are trying to show.

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense; You have a section for each user and you are displaying posts in the rows; but then you try and use `indexpath.row` to access your `users` array if the row is 1 , and presumably you have only 1 user in the `users` array, so you get an array bounds error

Comment: I'm sorry my friend now I but explain. for giving me im just beginner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanx, my friend, I found a good way to contain my cell. for post cell, i just use `cellForRowAt` and but the post data. for header cell i use `viewForHeaderInSection`
and but my user data with `heightForHeaderInSection`. to make the high for a view

Answer (score 0):

try this one.

```
cell.tag = indexpath.row
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Thankyou for your suggestion :) i will surely keep that in mind while answering :)

Answer (score 0):

What is the content of users array ?

Are you sure you want to define as many sections as users or as many rows ?
In this case use

```
func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
    return users.count
}
```

As explained, you need to rewrite completely cellForRowAt

It should look like this :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {

    if row < users.count {
        let user = users[row]
        if let cellView = tableView.makeView(withIdentifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "CellID"), owner: self) {
            (cellView as! NSTableCellView).textField?.stringValue = user.name
            // do the same for all the fields you need to set
            return cellView
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```